# Android: Problem using recycler view in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` in Fragment `ImagesliderFragment` First it gives an expection of "recyclerview must not be null" so on stackover flow I got an answer that you should intialized your recyclerview by using following line

```
  frag_rv = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView
```

But problem is that it gives me error on view. that `only safe or non null asserted calls are allowed` also my RecyclerView is not resolving can anyone explain me this what is the problem ?

[image: code screenshot]

**ImagesliderFragment**

```
class ImagesliderFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false)
    frag_rv = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView
    frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

}
```

Comment: put val before  frag_rv = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class ImagesliderFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {


    val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false)
    val frag_rv = myView.findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView
    frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)

    return myView
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

}
```

#### [Also now  no need to do `findViewById()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding)

SAMPLE CODE

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
// import here your layout file like this
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_imageslider.view.*

class ImagesliderFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false)

        myView.frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)

        return myView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your onCreateView method to:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) = 
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false).apply {
    frag_rv = findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView //val frag_rv if it's not declared elsewhere 
    frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)
}
```

This way the view is inflated(via inflater.inflate) and you are using it to find the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use `view.findViewById` you have to initialize it, also use `val` before `frag_rv` like the following.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

  // here you have to initialize your view
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false)
  val frag_rv = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_rv) as RecyclerView
  frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)

  return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the onCreateView method to inflate the view and bind the iew in the onViewCreated method

```
class ImagesliderFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imageslider, container, false)!!

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val frag_rv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.frag_rv)            frag_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, 
            false)
    }
}
```